# Expressjs - Mongoose: Unable to Find Property Value of Record

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm running into an issue where I am able to access the records associated with my mongoose model object, but I cannot access the properties of the records using dot notation. For some reason I can get the record, but when I try to use dot notation to grab that records specific property, I get `undefined`.

Here is my model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var imageSchema = new Schema({
    pattern: { type: String, enum: ['solid', 'stripe', 'plaid'] },
    color: { type: String, enum: ['grey', 'navy-blue', 'black', 'khaki', 'brown'] },
    imageName: String,
    imageUrl: String,
    imageSource: String
});

var Images = mongoose.model('Images', imageSchema);

module.exports = Images;
```

Here is my route being defined:

```
router.get('/:pattern/:color/result', function(req, res){

    console.log(req.params.color);

    Images.find( { pattern: req.params.pattern, color: req.params.color }, function(err, image){
        if (err) { console.log(err); }
        console.log(image);
        console.log(image.pattern);

        res.render('pages/result.hbs', {
            pattern : req.params.pattern,
            color : req.params.color,
            image : image
        });
    });
});
```

The console.log(image) retrieves records like:

```
[ { _id: 55e35b3b9bd509dbc0b46c79,
    pattern: 'solid',
    color: 'navy-blue',
    imageName: 'blueshirtesrsasdfff.jpg',
    imageUrl: 'https://imageurl.com',
    imageSource: 'source.com' } ]
```

The console.log(image.pattern) retrieves this response:

`undefined`

Where am I making a mistake and calling a specific property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.find` returns an array of elements (you can tell by the square brackets surrounding the image object in your console.log). If you want to keep your query the same, you'll actually need to use `image[0].pattern`.

Alternatively, you can use `Images.findOne`, like so

```
Images.findOne( { pattern: req.params.pattern, color: req.params.color }, function(err, image){
   if (err) { console.log(err); }

   ...
});
```

Comment: Would I still need to use `.find` with [0] or `findOne` even if I want to use all of the records that fit my query criteria? I would like to make the records that fit the criteria accessible to all be display within my view

Comment: Then stick with .find and just render { image: images } instead. There's nothing actually wrong with your code, it's just that your console.log isn't returning the thing you think it is. :)

Comment: I don't believe that is the right solution. { image: images } gives me a `ReferenceError: images is not defined` error. When I just try to use the image handler like `image.pattern` I should at least see a record like the example above with `solid`, but I don't.

Comment: Did you change the callback to `function (err,images)`? You won't see a record because again, it's an array.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are correct. your first suggestion works `image[0].pattern` for my console log. I needed to set up a loop within my view to get all of the records